# Applescript Iterate UIElements using Javascript

Tags: javascript, applescript, javascript-automation

Could someone please help me to make a script that reports all the children and its properties of an uielement? It's similar to entireContents() function. Here's my recursive function.

```
function iterate(obj) {
    for (var property in obj) {
        if(obj[property] instanceof Array) {
            console.log("Array: " + property + "," +obj[property])
            iterate(obj[property])
        } else if(obj[property] instanceof Object){
            console.log("Object: " + property + ',' + obj[property])
            iterate(obj[property])
        } else {
            console.log("Unknown: " + property +"," + obj[property]);
        }
    }
}
iterate(app.windows())
```

I only get the first level. There are bunch of UIElements and arrays under each item. I think it has to do with Applescript returning object specifier, but not actual object? I'm not sure how to invoke name of the object specifier as function. I tried objproperty, obj.property(), eval("obj." + property + "()"), ,and none of them works. I also tried iterate(app.windows())[0]
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I presume you want to use the commands in the `Processes Suite` of "**System Events**".

- To get a property of an `UIElement`, you must use one of these properties:

> (*accessibilityDescription, class, description, enable, entireContents,
>   focused, help, maximumValue, minimumValue, name, orientation,
>   position, role, roleDescription, selected, size, subrole, title,
>   value*)

- Example to get the name: `obj[i].name()`.

---

To get all UIElements from an UIElement, you must use `obj[i].uiElements()`

Here's an example on the windows of the "**TextEdit**" process.

```
function iterate(obj) {
    for (var i in obj) {
        if(obj[i] instanceof Array) {
            iterate(obj[i])
        } else if(obj[i] instanceof Object){
            console.log("Object: " + i + ': name = ' + obj[i].name() + ', value = ' + obj[i].value() + ', class = ' + obj[i].class() + ', description = ' + obj[i].description())
            iterate(obj[i].uiElements())
        }
    }
}
var sysEv = Application('System Events')
var app = sysEv.processes['TextEdit']
iterate(app.windows())
```

Comment: Thanks alot! obj.uiElements() was what was missing!